# How to parse and only get the EPC data from UHF tag?

Tags: android, flutter, rfid

I am using bluetooth low enery (BLE) method to read UHF passive tags.

The reading of tags works fine. I am just not sure how to separate the other information and only obtain the "EPC" data.

For example, the EPC data of the tag is `2b00`.

I get this `List<int>` when I read it.

`[1, 0, 70, 246, 170, 18, 0, 0, 9, 0, 2, 43, 0, 8, 0, 1, 1, 69, 234, 89]`

Then, I convert it to `Hex`:

```
String dataHex = hex.encode(data);
print(dataHex); // gives me: '010046f6aa1200000900022b000800010145ea59'
```

As we can see the EPC data `2b00` is shown within the String. Now I am not sure what the rest of the information is exactly about, could be the `CRC` ,`TID` & `user data`.

Could someone point me in the right direction on how to separate and isolate these values from the `hex` string, please?

Comment: Hi, which RFID reader are you using? does come with any SDK?

Comment: A Rain RFID (UHF C1G2) tag comes with 4 banks of memory, 3 of them are required (TID, Password, and EPC), 1 is optional (User Memory), and that depends on the tag chip model. Most of the time if you haven't changed the reader configuration, the reader must be reading the EPC memory bank, by default, it should be 96 bits (24 Hex digits), but it could be more, so when you said that it read the epc 2B00, it doesn't make any sense, can you provide more information?

Comment: Hi @MarioV
Thanks for your valuable insights, actually the 2B00 is a value that I wrote to the tag.  I contacted the RFID reader developer and they provided the correct commands to read the data (EPC, TID and user data)